# Access Logic in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access-2007

I am trying to figure out how a statement in Access is producing the output - so that I can write it in SQL Server - however I am not familiar with the "IIF" function but I have heard in Server you would use the case function.  Could anyone translate what the following piece of code is trying to say - the end result in the query is a number of days (TRANSIT) - I just cannot understand how they are getting there via this piece of query.  It seems very jumbled, going from plant code to somehow producing a transit time.

```
IIf(plant_code = "6010", [6010], [6041]) AS TRANSIT,
aship_date + IIf(
   DatePart('w',aship_date) < IIf(plant_code = "6010", [6010], [6041]) * - 1 + 7,
   IIf(plant_code = "6010", [6010], [6041]),
   IIf(plant_code = "6010", [6010], [6041]) + 2
      - Round(DatePart('w', aship_date) / 13, 0)
) AS ESTIMATED_DELIVERY_DATE
```

***Thanks for all of the feedback, converting these Access queries can be confusing.  I posted how it would look (entire code) if I formatted it - I really thing there are some business questions I need to ask to clarify as the use of "IIF" is so prevalent and if it is equal to CASE then that is strange.  6010,6040(which seems to be missing),and 6041 are physical plants, not a column - they fall under the column "plant_code" and so I think it could be a situation where I could create a new table on the server representing the values I need for transit to compare against based on the plant (this I could also alter when needed).  Additionally the table "t" is a temporary table only created within Access and much of the data is out of date.  I think the best route would be to remove the JOIN and see where I can cut out the IIF statements and just have conditions based on a second, more reliable transit table.  I really appreciate everybody's help, this has been very informative.  Full code (as I have laid out in SQL Server for the time being - also original table "O" was a composite via UNION ALL on the actual server):

```
SELECT t.DM, 
       t.AREA,
       t.STORE, 
       t.STORE_NAME, 
       "(" & T.STORE & ") " & T.STORE_NAME AS LOCATION, 
       O.WHSE, O.PO_NUMBER, 
       O.SHIPPED_UNITS, 
       O.CARTON_COUNT, 
       O.ASHIP_DATE AS ACTUAL_SHIP_DATE, 
       IIf(plant_code ='6010',[6010],[6041]) AS TRANSIT, 
       aship_date+IIf(DatePart('w',aship_date)<IIf(plant_code="6010",[6010],[6041])*-1+7,
       IIf(plant_code="6010",[6010],[6041]),IIf(plant_code="6010",[6010],[6041])+2-Round(DatePart          ('w',aship_date)/13,0)) AS ESTIMATED_DELIVERY_DATE, 
       O.CARRIER, 
       MAX(O.TrackingNo) AS TRACKING_NUMBER, 
       O.DeliveryStatus AS STATUS, 
       O.DeliveryDate AS DELIVERY_DATE
FROM VW_ADIDAS_RETAIL_aRI
UNION ALL VW_ADIDAS_RETAIL_aRO O
JOIN  tstores AS t
WHERE (((O.SHIP_TO)=[t].[DC_ACCT]) 
AND  O.process_date >= GETDATE()-60 
AND  O.order_status IN ('SHP','90')
AND  O.DeliveryDate IS NULL
GROUP BY t.DM, 
         t.AREA, 
         t.STORE, 
         t.STORE_NAME, 
         O.WHSE, 
         O.PO_NUMBER, 
         O.SHIPPED_UNITS, 
         O.CARTON_COUNT, 
         O.ASHIP_DATE, 
         IIf(plant_code="6010",[6010],[6041]), 
         O.CARRIER, 
         O.DeliveryStatus, 
         O.DeliveryDate;
```

Comment: `IIF` is `IIF(boolean test, true result, false result)`.  Case is `CASE WHEN x then y`.  So `case when plant_codein (6010, 6041) then aship_date end` for the first one.

Comment: You have some messy column names. Can you tell me what columns `[6010]` and `[6041]` are? Also this code makes no sense to me at all: `Round(DatePart('w',aship_date)/13,0)`. `DatePart` gives you a number representing each day in the week, 0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, etc. By dividing by 2, then round it, I guess it's trying to stick to some "every other day" logic?

Comment: @ZoffDino Sunday = 1, Saturday = 7. That expression turns Sunday through Friday into 0 and Sunday into 1. You can think of it as `Iif(DatePart('w', aship_date) = 7, 1, 0)`.

Comment: *I have heard in Server you would use the case function* [`IIF` was introduced in SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/hh213574(v=sql.110).aspx). Presumably you are not using SQL Server 2012 or 2014.

Answer (score 1):

Unless, I misunderstand, the [6010] and [6041] are columns within a table. 
The fact that plant_code can also be 6010 adds to the confusion. 
For the first (simpler one) it's saying if plant_code is 6010, use the value in the 6010 column, otherwise the 6041 column. (I'll call this the Transit number below)

For the second, take the aship_date and the above value if the day of the week for aship_date is less than the Transit number - 1 + 7, otherwise Take the transit number + 2 - the nearest integer to the day of the week of aship_date / 13. Which btw, unless it's Sat should be 0, if it's Sat then subtract 1.

It could help if I knew the actual contents of the numeric columns to help really describe it.

Comment: it is strange, I think "6010" and [6010] are the same thing - 6010 & 6041 are plant codes, I don't see how specifying it in quotes and then brackets makes a difference.  Thanks to all for the help, this has been very informative.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate conversion would be

```
CASE WHEN plant_code="6010" THEN [6010] ELSE [6041] END AS TRANSIT, 
aship_date + CASE WHEN 
        DatePart(WEEKDAY,aship_date) < 7 - CASE WHEN plant_code="6010" THEN [6010] ELSE [6041] END
          THEN 
              CASE WHEN plant_code="6010" THEN [6010] ELSE [6041] END  
          ELSE  
              CASE WHEN plant_code="6010" THEN [6010] ELSE [6041] END + 2 - ROUND(DatePart(WEEKDAY,aship_date)/13,0) 
          END AS ESTIMATED_DELIVERY_DATE
```

But in this case it would be MUCH simpler and more readable to use `CROSS APPLY`

```
SELECT 
    TRANSIT, 
    aship_date + case when DatePart(WEEKDAY,aship_date) < 7 - TRANSIT
                    THEN TRANSIT
                    ELSE TRANSIT + 2 - ROUND(DatePart(WEEKDAY,aship_date)/13.0,0) 
                 END AS ESTIMATED_DELIVERY_DATE
FROM <TABLE>
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN plant_code="6010" THEN [6010] ELSE [6041] END) N(TRANSIT)
```

---

**THE CODE IN WORDS**

To understand code, keep in mind that plant_code will define which column will be the transit value - 6010 or 6041.

***Calculating the adjusted transit number of days***

If the day of the week plus transit is a day different from sunday, then it will take the transit amount of days. Otherwise, it will take transit + 2 - the day of the week of the shipment date divided by 13 (**it will be one only for sunday**).

In other words, if the estimated delivery date using conventional transit number of days is different from sunday, use the conventional number of transit days. Otherwise, if shipment date is sunday then use the `transit + 1` else use the `transit + 2`.

To get estimated delivery delivery date, they take the weekday of shipment date plus the amount of adjusted transit calculated above.

The code

```
ROUND(DatePart(WEEKDAY,aship_date)/13,0)
```

is the same of

```
CASE WHEN DatePart(WEEKDAY,aship_date) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

---

I would like to thank @ErikE, who provided this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f224f/30)

Comment: I think your calculations about Saturday are incorrect... datepart 7 is **Sunday**. "SET DATEFIRST 7, Sunday, is the default for U.S. English." [DATEPART (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx). A business that's open on Sunday, but not Saturday, would be very strange!

Comment: Nizam, I did some more study, and found that the original expression was not calculating dates correctly. I'm afraid I misled you. I highly recommend you run the original expression against some test data to see what it's doing. I was tracking with you closely, myself, from a mere analysis of the expression--and I think that you (and I) are seeing what it's *trying* to do, but not what it's *actually* doing (which I believe to be erroneous).

Comment: Anyway the code is a literal translation of the Access code. The OP could give some examples of values and result it gives. It would help a LOT.

Comment: Please see [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f224f). Note that a Transit of 0 may be invalid, and higher transit values (5 and up?) may also be invalid. Let me know if I got anything wrong.

Comment: @ErikE, this SQL Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f224f/30) shows that the problem occurs when transit is greater than 5 (I didn't find the transit equals zero problem), but more than this, when weekday of shipment date plus transit is equal or more than 12 days (two entire businnes week plus one weekend). It seems they are worried about just one weekend. Maybe transit is always equal or less than 5 (on entire business week). The OP needs to say something. *PS: How to add link alias here in comments?*

Comment: I would like to thank all who helped on this..it has been a HUGE help.  I think there are more questions to be asked of the business in terms of logic.  I need to see why they were using all of these conditions when possibly we could create a another table with basic transit data that is more easily updated and could provide much easier access.

Comment: Something I would like to question is: Is it possible to have transit values greater than 5?